# c# - expected name not found

Tags: c#, graphql

I have the following GraphQl query, which works fine in PostMan.

```
query getFirstName($id: String!) {
  getFirstName(id: $id) {
    myId
  }
}
```

However, when I am executing using the traditional `HttpClient` module I get the error

```
code":400,"stacktrace":"Syntax Error: Expected Name, found \"$
```

My Code:

```
var queryObject = new
{
    query = @"query {
     getFirstName($id: String!) {
      getFirstName(id: $id) {
       myId
      }
    }
  }",
    variables = new { id = "132" }
};

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);


var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryObject);
var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
var responseTask = httpClient.PostAsync(myUri, byteContent);
responseTask.Wait();
var response = responseTask.Result;
```

I think my `queryObject` is not parsed correctly.